# Support v7 ActionBarActivity, OnCreateOptionsMenu() called after each call to SupportInvalidateOptionsMenu()

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-lifecycle, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

In my `Activity` which is a Support v7 `ActionBarActivity`, I have menu and a navigation drawer.

When ever the navigation drawer is open I want to hide the menu items.
I hide them in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

As stated in the documentation from android, in order to trigger an `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` you need to call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`.

I'm doing just that. But after I call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`, the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called and than the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

As I understood the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` should be called only once at the beginning of the `Activity`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Sound valid to me. Can you post some code?

Comment: My code is divided in more classes ( MainActivity, ActionBarManager, NavDrawersGuiManager and NavDrowerToggle). So I'll go for the code pasting if there is no other suggestion. What do you think about the answer from ZygoteInit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct cycle is:

- Calling `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` leads to the menu getting
  recreated, i.e. `onCreateOptionsMenu()` gets called.
- Whenever `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called, `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`
  is called to prepare the menu.

So calling `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` will always lead to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` getting called. Hope this helps clear the confusion.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly as it happens. Why is supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(). different from invalidateOptionsMenu()?. The invalidateOptionsMenu() is described here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html.

Comment: `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` is used in `FragmentActivity` on platforms below API 14 which use the appcompat-v7 library. It has the same behavior and purpose as `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: As stated here developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html  :  when   invalidateOptionsMenu() --> onPrepareOptionsMenu() will be called without onCreateOptionsMenu().   This is not the case for supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() -->onCreateOptionsMenu() --> onPrepareOptionsMenu().  So basically if I use the support version the behavior is a little bit different?

Comment: nothing like that is written on that page ... where have you read this ?

Comment: My bad. I read it again and also read the documentation for "public void invalidateOptionsMenu ()". Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs to be displayed.  Now I got it thank you!